# What is preferred approach to deploy Python app using RPM?

Tags: python, rpm, chef, deployment

I am new to the dev-ops side of things, and I've been working to get a Python application packaged into an RPM (using python setup.py bdist_rpm) deployed onto a centos VM via Yum. Chef is used to manage the VM. The Python app will run within a virtualenv, as part of a continuous deployment process.

Should the RPM be smart and self-contained, performing such operations as creating/starting the virtualenv environment, pip-installing required dependencies and then finally configuring an init process (in this case to kick off a uwsgi REST server process for the virtualenv)?

Or, should the Chef recipe manage building the virtualenv and pip-installing dependencies, with the RPM itself doing a simple 'python setup.py install' to load my Python modules into the virtualenv's pythonX.Y/site-packages folder?

A follow on 'yum install/reinstall ' call (say via an automated process) would work for either approach, but the former requires a more complex RPM which may not be 'best practice', correct?  The former does allow for a self-contained install that could be more cleanly removed later, and better separates concerns between developer (Python) and dev-ops (Chef). Please advise on what is 'typically' done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/python) Chef cookbook seems to be pretty good. It provides support for what you're looking to do. For what is typically done I can only approach it from a Puppet standpoint, but I don't see a reason to add that sort of complexity to the RPM when it is easily supported by a cookbook. You're simply creating more work for yourself later when you need to make changes, and making it harder for other users to support.

Comment: Thanks Forrest, I am using this plugin, but it seems best for situations where all of your python app (so app + dependencies) is deployed via the pip process into a virtualenv. The devops folks are preferring that we package our app in an RPM (or Debian) package though, so doing a pip install approach for the app's dependencies but using the RPM just to copy our app's Python files into the virtual env's site-packages folder seems awkward to me.

Comment: Their reasoning is fair, and if that works best for you then you should go for it. My only concern is being burned down the road. I've had a lot of RPMs I had to rip the configuration files out of to put into Puppet so they were easier to manage, and it just resulted in a lot of extra work. I'm not extremely familiar with Chef, but can't you put the configuration file requirements, along with the RPM into a single recipe and make it so that the configuration files require that the RPM has been installed?

Comment: I believe so Forrest, I'll take a look, thank you.